# perl updating a hash value after searching by value

Tags: perl

I'm trying to write my first Perl program where I update a value in a hash with given value:

```
sub changeMap {
    my $done = 0;
    my $daKey = 'a';
    while($done == 0)
    {
        print "Please select the character you would like to remap: ";
        my $selection1 = <STDIN>;
        print "You selected $selection1\n";
        print "Please select the character you would like to replace it with: ";
        my $selection2 = <STDIN>;
        my %tempHash = reverse %mapping;
        my $daKey = $tempHash{$selection1};
        print "$daKey";
        $mapping{$daKey} = $selection2;
        my $done1 = 0;
        while($done1 == 0) {
            print "Would you like to replace another? (y or n) ";
            my $answer = <STDIN>;
            if ($answer == 'y') {
                $done1 = 1;
            }
            elsif ($answer == 'n') {
                $done = 1;
                $done1 = 1;
            }
            else {
                print "Not a valid response.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $daKey in string at ./lastlab.pl line 117, <STDIN>
    line 2 (#1)
(W uninitialized) An undefined value was used as if it were already
defined.  It was interpreted as a "" or a 0, but maybe it was a mistake.
To suppress this warning assign a defined value to your variables.

To help you figure out what was undefined, perl will try to tell you the
name of the variable (if any) that was undefined. In some cases it cannot
do this, so it also tells you what operation you used the undefined value
in.  Note, however, that perl optimizes your program and the operation
displayed in the warning may not necessarily appear literally in your
program.  For example, "that $foo" is usually optimized into "that "
. $foo, and the warning will refer to the concatenation (.) operator,
even though there is no . in your program.
```

Any suggestions? I can't see exactly where my problem is. I'm new to Perl and it looks like I'm having some issues.

Comment: Always put `use strict; use warnings`

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` and post the exact error you receive. Guessing you might have a problem with line endings, too. See [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html).

Comment: I used both strict and warnings. This is just one subroutine of a larger program.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to tell us which line is line 117 (the one where the warning is generated), but, from the warning you get, it should be this one:

```
print "$daKey";
```

The warning tells us that `$daKey` is undefined, so how would that happen?

Well, it gets its value from the preceding line:

```
my $daKey = $tempHash{$selection1};
```

So, if `$daKey` is undefined, then `$tempHash{$selection1}` must be undefined.  How would *that* happen?

In the general case, this could happen in one of two ways:

1. `$selection1` exists in `%tempHash`, but has an undefined value
2. `$selection1` does not exist in `%tempHash`

However, in this specific case, `%temphash` gets its value from `reverse %mapping`.  This (to a first approximation) swaps the keys and values of `%mapping` and hashes can't have undefined keys, therefore `%temphash` can't have undefined values, so #2 *must* be the case: `$selection1` identifies a key which does not exist in `%temphash`.

Now that we know this, we again ask ourselves the central question of debugging:  "How would that happen?"

Well, `$selection1` gets its value from the line

```
my $selection1 = <STDIN>;
```

So this *could* just be user error - the user could be entering a value which is not a value in `%mapping` (and, therefore, not a key in `%temphash`) and your code makes no attempt to detect or handle such an error.

The more likely case, however, is that you need to `chomp $selection1` to remove the `\n` (newline) character from the end of it.  Input received from a filehandle (such as `<STDIN>`) will pretty much always end with a newline, while internal data pretty much never will, which prevents them from being equal to each other.